# PowerBI embedded working for some users but login screen not showing for me

Tags: asp.net, powerbi, unauthorized, powerbi-embedded

I have power BI embedded into my ASP.NET web application and is working for other developers and works on a previous computer but now I have a new computer without the last and it doesn't work.

after entering the web application, and clicking on the power BI button, for others, it shows a Office 365 login screen but for me, it appears and then disappears without giving the chance to enter in my details, therefore returning an error, of an unauthorized user.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykXOe.png

I have tested and cleared cookies, session variables and any history from my computer so don't believe it is that.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: any help is appreciated please

Comment: Problem solved.